# Nasm X86 64 Push two variables to the stack and sum them

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm working on writing a language that will compile to assembly and am in the process of handling variables. I'm setting the variable `x` to `1` and `y` to `2` and then trying to sum them with the resulting assembly from my compiler looking like:

```
;; Start of program
section .text
    global _start
section .var_1
    number_1 dw 1
section .var_2
    number_2 dw 2
section .text
    _start:
    push qword [number_1]
    push qword [number_2]
    ;; Add
    pop rax
    pop rbx
    add rax, rbx
    push rax
    ;; Exit
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

This gets compile through the commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 out.asm
ld -o out out.o
```

When I run `gdb` and step through, I see the `2` value being popped into `rax` but when I pop into `rbx` it seems like it's popping a reference as it's a pretty large number.

Comment: `dw` defines a 16 bit word. You want `dq` for a 64 bit quad word.

Comment: Does the first value, `2`, get popped correctly with the second value, `1`, being popped incorrectly because of alignment of the data then? And if so, is it safe to assume that a `dq` is over allocating memory for such small numbers?

Comment: It doesn't matter how large your number is, what matters is how you use it. You wrote `push qword` so you need qwords. Yes, if you know your numbers will be smaller you can then use smaller units, but in both places so they match. Referencing a bigger chunk of memory than what you initialized will give you random data in the other parts at best, or crash at worst.

Comment: Good to know. Appreciate the swift response!

Comment: Use hex for "large numbers" and you'll see it's `0x00020001`.  You loaded 8 bytes that spanned both 2-byte numbers and 4 more bytes of presumably zeros later in the `.data` section.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CPU isn't aware of the size your data was intended to be. If you do `push qword [label]` it's going to push the 8 bytes that are stored at `label` regardless of whether you wrote them as `db, dw, dd,` or `dq`. There's no type checking in assembly at all.